# Using similarity matrix as a correlation input

Tags: correlation, similarities, hierarchical-clustering

I am using an approach to decompose sigmoidal signals in R. Briefly, signals are decomposed into a subset of components and then a custom value of similarity is computed among samples defined by 2 factors (M = MRS and BSG and S = PU1, WCFS1 and H46), each sample has 2 replicates. I expect a grouping by M or S.

I tried to use this similarity measurement as a distance matrix to perform clustering, but the results make literally no sense. However, when I use this similarity matrix as an input for a  correlation it gave nice results for different data inputs. I have never read about using a similarity matrix as an input for correlations. Is it statistically correct to do so?

```
hclust(as.dist(M1), method = "ward.D2")
cor(M1, method = "kendall"), type="upper", order="hclust", col=brewer.pal(n=8, name="RdYlBu")
```

[image: Clustering]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The way hierarchical clustering works is, it finds two samples that have the smallest distance from the distance matrix you provide, merge them into one meta-sample, update its distances to other samples (depending on the method you specify), and then move on to merge the next closest samples ...

Since you provided the similarity matrix as the distance matrix, hclust actually **merged samples that have the least similarity** at each step. It totally makes sense that the clustering results didn't make sense.

If you want to see sensible results, you can use some transformation to make your similarity matrix into a distance matrix. Just make sure the transformation maps low similarity into large distance, and high similarity into small distance. For example, if your similarities are correlations (bounded by -1, 1), a frequently used transformation is 1 - correlation. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45896231/r-corrplot-with-clustering-default-dissimilarity-measure-for-correlation-matrix), this is exactly what corrplot uses to order the samples.

In your corrplot results, the clustering is based on cor(M1, method = "kendall"), i.e. correlations of samples' similarities with all the samples. It sometimes may not make sense. For example, sample S1 has similarities (10, 0, 9, 8, 7, 6) with (S1, S2, S3, S4, S5, S6), and sample S2 has similarities (0, 10, 4, 3, 2, 1) with the samples. S1 and S2 have 0 similarity, yet the correlation of the two similarity vectors are pretty good.

I would prefer hclust with similarities transformed into distances to the corrplot method, because cor(M1) has the undesirable property I just mentioned, and is also harder to interpret.